# How to display an image that is selected in one view in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I used the code below in iOS to pick an image from the photo library. I need to display this image in different view. How should I proceed?

```
//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSArray *theViewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

    [imgview setImage:image]; //set in image view

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:nil];
}
```

I tried the below code to display the image in next view but it is not working??

```
//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSArray *theViewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

    //[imgview setImage:image]; //set in image view
    ImageViewController *adjViewController = (ImageViewController *)[theViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [adjViewController.imageview1 setImage :image]; 

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:nil];        
}
```

Comment: have you used app delegate variable ?

Comment: @iManan Can you brief..Am bit new to OC

Comment: @iManan:your are not passing the image into the view

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `UIImage *image` (from your `imagePickerController` method) global to its view controller and then pass it `prepareForSegue`.

For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextView"]) {
        ImageViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setImage:image];
    }
}
```

Then in your `ImageViewController.h` you just need something like:

```
@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImage *image;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

And synthesise it in the .m and set the image to your `imageView` in `viewWillAppear`. You can read the docs for `prepareForSegue` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW84).

Comment: at this line am getting syntax error! it should be image view rit?

Comment: Oh sorry!! here [vc setImage:image];

Comment: Make sure your view controller is imported at the top (I think its called `ImageViewController`) and that you have a property in that called image. If you start typing [vc set... it should prompt you as to what it detects on that view. If setImage doesn't come up, perhaps it has been typed differently. Failing that, perhaps you can't use `image` so try `largeImage` or something more appropriate.

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NavToRechoose"]) {
        RechooseImageViewController *adjViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [adjViewController.imageview1 setImage: image];
    }
}  This is the code I did and still it didnt workout @Patrick

Comment: No, you can't set the `imageView` directly because it has not been created yet. You need to set an image like I have done above - much like passing over any variable. And in the `viewDidLoad` or another method (like `viewWillAppear`), this is where you set the image to the imageView. I think [this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich - Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) might be worth reading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26370/discussion-between-patrick-and-2vision2)